# Leaflet: Style function does not work for point layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet and I'm not very proficient in Javascript. I've been trying to create a map visualizing a point layer with custom markers but for some reason the marker style as a function just doesn't work whereas marker style as a variable does. I've checked multiple resources and answers but I just can't seem to figure out why - it's probably something simple I'm missing. Here's the code that works:

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
radius: 2.5,
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8
};

minesLayer= L.geoJson(
mines, 
{ pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions
    );
} }
).addTo( tnmap );
```

And here's the code that doesn't:

```
function minesStyle(feature) {
    return {
        radius: 2.5,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    }
}

minesLayer= L.geoJson(
mines, 
{ pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        style: minesStyle
        }
    );
} }
).addTo( tnmap );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code snippet, you're using the [`style` option for `L.GeoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson-style) as if it were an [valid option for `L.CircleMarker`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#circlemarker).

Read the documentation carefully again and ask yourself: Does `L.CircleMarker` use a `style` option?

A better way would be to calculate styles inside `pointToLayer`, e.g.:

```
var layer = L.geoJson(data, {
    pointToLayer: function(feat, ll) {
        var styleForThisFeature = minesStyle(feat);
        var featureForThisPoint = L.circleMarker(ll, styleForThisFeature);
        return featureForThisPoint;
    }
}).addTo(map)
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you! I didn't check the documentation properly enough to realise that I was using my functions wrong.

Comment: Yeah, if you're new to Leaflet it's easy to overlook this kind of things.